# ESXI Cannot start up from Virtual IDE Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

After an power outage my ESXi at home cannot boot one of my virtual machines.

When i start the VM I get the following error message:

[image: Attempting to start up from: VMWware Virtual IDE Hard Drive (IDE0:0) unsuccessful]

I already tried to connect via ssh to ESXi and ran `vmkfstools -x check HOS-HA-1.vmdk` which resulted in `Disk is error free`.

[image: Directory structure of the VM folder]

I have a .vmdk and a -flat.vmdk file.

The system that should be running in the VM is Hass.io (Homeassistant .ova)

Do you have any ideas what I could try to get the VM running again?

Comment: You have verified the specified VHD file exists and is accessible? Just to clarify, ESXi is running within a VM or metal hardware?

Comment: ESXi is running bare-metal

[This is the directory structure of the VM folder.](https://imgur.com/a/FBNmo6l)

I have a .vmdk and a -flat.vmdk file.

The system that should be running in the VM is Hass.io (Homeassistant .ova)

Comment: The image is inaccessible since you did not use the [edit] feature and upload the image.

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question and added the image :)
And added it now correctly ;)

Comment: Does the contents of the log(s) show any indication what might be happening during the process of identifying and processing the virtual hdd?

Comment: [Recent log looks like the disk is OK](https://pastebin.com/NwgwtMP6)
[.vmx file](https://pastebin.com/uDeMe8qR)

Comment: I am not posting this as answer, because it will not be a answer for somebody else but i fixed my problem like this: i "resolved" it by installing a new vm from the latest ova file.
mounting the corrupted vmdk file and the newly created vmdk file on a ubuntu vm.
mounted the two vmdk's and copied the data from the old one to the new one.

now the system is up and running and has the data from the old system.
with all supervisor container and everything (at least it looks like it until now)